# Starting John the Rippper via a python script

Tags: python, macos, security, hash, cracking

So yeah, I've been working on a python script that extracts the password hash from a Mac.
Now I wanna take it to the next level, crack it.
After some quick research i found John the Ripper(http://www.openwall.com/john/) and decided to try and use that. (Note: I have tried other softwares, but none of them have been able to crack my test-hash.
The problem is, when i try to start john the ripper, it fails me. (Im using some custom mac 1.7.3 version, haven't tried updating yet and I would prefer not to)
Current script(after about 1 000 000 changes and retries:

```
output__ = "1dc74ff22b199305242d62f76f6a5c5c47b4c2e3"
print output__
txt = file('john/sha1.txt','wt')
sha1textfile = "%s:%s" % (output2[0], output__)
txt.write(sha1textfile)
txt2 = file('startjohn.command', 'wt')
stjtextfile = """
#!/bin/bash
cd /hax/john
./run/john sha1.txt
"""
txt2.write(stjtextfile)
shell('chmod 777 startjohn.command')
shell('open startjohn.command')
```

Now I the error i get is:

```
/hax/startjohn.command ; exit;
My-MacBook:~ albertfreakman$ /hax/startjohn.command ; exit;
No password hashes loaded
logout
```

Help me solve this problem and save me from insanity!
Sincerely, Duke.

Some quick notes:

1. Output__ is my test hash, already got the extract hash part working.
2. If you have a solution that uses any other Hashcracker than John, thats even better! As long as it can either use a wordlist, or bruteforce.
3. The hash is SHA1

Thanks!

Comment: unless running `open startjohn.command` in a shell gives you a different result, this isn't a python (or programming) problem at all

Comment: Well, It doesn't sadly.
But what I need is a solution, I need to run john the ripper from a python script, how it is done doesn't matter. :)

Comment: If you can't run John in a shell without the python script, then we can't help you here. That's really a John / OSX problem.

Comment: As @Kyle Maxwell said. You may want to focus on getting it to work from the CLI first. For that, you may want to check [Superuser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: Well I can run it in the terminal, no problems there.
It's just when I try to run it from python.
Still, if there is ANY working option that cracks SHA1 passwords that works when running from a python script, It works perfectly as well.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the problem, my test hash didn't have CAPITAL LETTERS and therefore weren't accepted by john the ripper.